# necessity of "will" to indicate the future even if there is tomorrow in the sentence

Tags: future-tense

> Jim  was talking with his parents earlier this evening when his girlfriend from Paris telephoned to let him know that Crossinglives & Co. had decided to merge with a company in Australia. The two companies had been negotiating for the past month, so it really was not much of a surprise. Of course, this means that Jim  will have to catch the next plane back to Paris. He  **will be meeting** with his boss at this time tomorrow.

Why "will be meeting" and not "is meeting" the meeting has been scheduled or planned is to insist to the continuity of the event, the word tomorrow indicates that the event  will take place in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be possible to use "is meeting" here, as it is a certain, timetabled future event. However there is nothing wrong with using "will meet"; it is a perfectly normal way of forming a future tense. Another alternative is "is going to meet".

However the word "tomorrow" is not enough. It would be odd to say "He meets with his boss tomorrow". This sounds like the meeting is an absolute unchanging fact, and would be a rare formation.

Generally the time adjective should match the tense in the verb. "He met with his boss tomorrow" is odd to the point of being nonsense.

Comment: *I meet with our new VP tomorrow.* would be not uncommon in AmE.  The present singular used in this way is often a reminder to another person of something they've already been told.   *You know I can't meet you for lunch. I meet with our new VP tomorrow.*    It's confirmed, something that is on the schedule or calendar.

Answer (score 0):

> He **is meeting** his boss at this time tomorrow.

...is a perfectly valid and understood sentence.

Personally, I would use that form to indicate some kind of imminence, that the thing is to take place relatively soon. To that end, I'd say either option is equally appropriate for the context you provided.